# auto adjust img width/height depending on parent width/height CSS HTML

Tags: image, html, css

I'm trying to fill a window with an image. I'm using CSS to try to work this, but I was wondering if there's a way to maximize the width/height of the image until all the white space is filled, but not ruin the quality.

```
<div class='rel-img-cont'>
    <img src='src.jpg' />
</div>

.rel-img-cont
{
    width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;
}
.rel-img-cont img
{
    height: 100px; margin:0 0 0 0;
}
```

How can I fill the white space so even if one of the sizes has to overflow, it will only go up to 100px.

Is there a way to do this even if the original image is say, 100px x 100px or 150px x 200px, no matter which one, 100px is max, so one of the sides will have to give.

Thanks

Comment: max-width/max-height?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code which is tested on my machine

```
 <style>
 .rel-img-cont
{
    width: 10%; height: 10%; overflow: hidden;
    border:3px solid orange;
}
.rel-img-cont img
{
    height: 100%; margin:0 0 0 0;
    width:100%;
}
 </style>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just remove the border property .I used it for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You may find [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) css property interesting. Because this property does the same which you are trying to approach here. But this will work for `background-image`.

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: I'm using PHP to generate the img src. I don't think I'll be able to use background-image unless I do style inline? Is this the only way?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with PHP. So, I can't comment about it.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use % instead of px in this case

```
<div id="Maindiv" style="width:100px;height:100px">
<img id="Img" src="http://blog.flattr.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/stackoverflow.png" alt="Image"  />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Maindiv img
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't think those position absolute really helps

Comment: And I think it just squeezes the images?

Comment: Yes it will squeeze the image or stretch the image to fit to the size specified. You can have the image in whatever % of size you want it to be in this way.

Comment: I'm not trying to "squeeze" the image. thats whyh I have overflow: hidden, i need to preserve the same size ratio

Comment: yeah, the width:100%; height:100% will ensure that it is not squeezed. If its not a square image, you need to change the width height of the container i.e Maindiv

Comment: downvotes pls drop in a comment so that i can improve the answer :)  tia

Answer (score 0):

> .rel-img-cont {
>       width: 100%; 
>       height: 100%;  } 
>   .rel-img-cont img {
>       height:100%; 
>       width:100%; }

Please see the [demo](http://jsbin.com/AlUguQeD/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can make width as 100% and leave the height to auto. And use only those img's which are proportionate to your div.